# Any way to read number of active workers of gunicorn managed by the arbiter from command line?

Tags: python, gunicorn, instrumentation

As explained [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/instrumentation.html)
Gunicorn provides an optional instrumentation of the arbiter and workers using the statsD protocol over UDP.

My question: Is there any way to read number of active (i.e. processing some request) gunicorn workers in realtime from command line without installing statsD? My server load average sometimes peaks and I want to see how many gunicorn workers are busy in that time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gunicorn's default statsd tracking doesn't actually track active vs nonactive workers. It just tells you the total number of workers, which is not nearly as useful.

But Gunicorn does provide server hooks to let you run code at various points in the process. This is the solution I came up with:

```
sc = statsd.StatsClient(domain, port, prefix=statsd_prefix)

def pre_request(worker, req):
    # Increment busy workers count
    sc.incr('busy_workers', 1)

def post_request(worker, req, environ, resp):
    # Decrement busy workers count
    sc.decr('busy_workers', 1)
```

You gotta put that in your config file and then reference the config file when you start up gunicorn.

`gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --config myapp/gunicorn_config.py`

If you don't want to use statsd you could use those same triggers but pipe a signal to any other program that can keep a count and then `watch` it to see it on the commandline.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. But if I'm not mistaken, your code keeps track of the count of requests being handled, which is only equal to the number of active workers if the number of threads per worker is set to 1?

Comment: You are correct that the above actually tracks 'active requests'. If each worker has multiple threads, then the above would be tracking active threads as each thread handles a different request concurrently. So in that case the concept of a 'busy worker' becomes less meaningful because a worker with 2 threads can have one thread busy and one thread not busy at the same time and 'active threads' becomes the more meaningful metric, which is what you'd be measuring.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is any particular command for it.

But generally it can be done using shell. `Number of workers mean number of processes.` Hence you can simple check all the active process, then find all the process which has gunicorn in it and then count all such entries. Do remember to exclude the grep search because it is also has gunicorn.

You command would look something like this.

> ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep | wc -l

Comment: It will give all workers even if they are inactive waiting for next reqeust

Comment: @Ali yes. So you want to know only active working workers?

Comment: Yes. I'm hoping to find an answer to this as well. Even using the statsD metrics that gunicorn exports, there is no easy way to determine at any given time how many workers are actively serving a request. It only shows total number of workers, which includes idle workers.